# Replying to a specific msg in telegraf framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, telegram-bot, telegraf

I'm making a telegram bot with `telegraf` frame work ( it means Node.js )
So I want when someone send `good morning` The bot will reply to his own msg, I searched alot but i didn't find the answer

Example:-
I want the reply to be like this

[image]

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like

```
bot.command(key, (ctx) => {
    ctx.reply('A Reply', {
        reply_to_message_id: ctx.message.message_id
    })
})
```

Answer (score -1):

The documentation for telegraf is here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/telegraf

From what I have read, this should work:

```
const { Telegraf } = require('telegraf')

const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.BOT_TOKEN)
bot.hears('good morning', (ctx) => ctx.reply('Good morning to you too!'))
bot.launch()

// Enable graceful stop
process.once('SIGINT', () => bot.stop('SIGINT'))
process.once('SIGTERM', () => bot.stop('SIGTERM'))
```

This is edited code from the first example in the docs.